# Properties of Continuous Time Markov Chains

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

In school, I only learned about about "Discrete Time Markov Chains" - in Discrete Time Markov Chains, transitions can only happen at fixed time points. For example, suppose there are three types of weathers (e.g. Sunny, Rainy, Cloudy) and the probability of the weather today only depends on the yesterday's weather. Provided we know the initial probabilities and the transition probabilities between these three types of weathers, I remember that it was possible to determine properties such as:

- The probability of a certain weather (e.g. Sunny, Rainy, Cloudy) after a certain number of days, provided the weather is known at the start
- The probability of a certain weather (e.g. Sunny, Rainy, Cloudy) after a certain number of days, regardless of the weather at the start

I am now trying to teach myself about "Continuous Time Markov Chains" - as I understand, now transitions can happen at arbitrary times. Suppose I have a similar question as I did in the example with the "Discrete Time Markov Chain", and a matrix of transition probabilities and transition intensities are known (and assume that the distribution of the sojourn time distributions have some probability distribution function p(x) ). Are there any straightforward formulas for determining:

- Provided "d" amount of time is spent in "state j", how much more time must **likely** elapse before the next transition happens?
- Provided "d" amount of time is spent in "state j", to which state will the next transition most **likely** lead us to?
- Provided "d" amount of time is spent in "state j", what is the probability of spending "d1" amount of time in "state j1" followed by "d2" amount of time in "state j2" followed by "d3" amount of time in "state j3"?

Is it possible to answer such questions with a Continuous Time Markov Chains?

Thank you!

**Note:** I am aware that the difference between a Markov Process and the Semi-Markov Process is the distribution of Sojourn Times. In a Markov Process, the distribution of these times can only be a Exponential Distribution - whereas in a Semi-Markov Process, this distribution does not necessarily have to be an Exponential Distribution (e.g. Weibull Distribution). I am aware that an Exponential Distribution has "convenient properties" such as the "Memoryless Property" - this means that the probability an spending an additional "d minutes" in a certain state provided that you have already spent "c minutes" in this state ... is not dependent on these prior "c minutes". However, I am not sure how to calculate expected Sojourn Times for a Semi-Markov Process with *any* probability distribution. Perhaps this must be solved using a simulation?

Comment: This is my guess, but I am guessing that "sojourn times" are basically the same thing as "inter arrival times"?

Comment: You should probably start studying Markov chains with finite state space. These are unambiguously defined by their semigroup of transition matrices $P(t)$. The difference of discrete and continuous time then is vanishing in the sense that the matrix tells you to what state the chain jumps in the "next" instance of time when it currently is in a given state. This has nothing to do with how much amount of time is spent in that state. The very notion of Markov is that what happens next only depends on what is now. Please give your question more focus and consider studying a book like Durret's.