# Why are Some Probability Distributions "Used More Often" for Certain Things?

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution

I have had this question for a long time - Why are Some Probability Distributions "Used More Often" for Certain Things?

I understand that for certain problems, the type of probability distribution to use is more or less obvious. For example, the probability of a two-sided coin is modelled using a Binomial Probability Distribution and the probability of a six-sided dice is modelled using a Multinomial Distribution.

But sometimes, the rationale behind why a certain probability distribution should be used is a bit unclear to me,

For example:

- When we deal with the "occurrences of events" (e.g. cars arriving per minute, formation of queue networks, failures and survival times, etc.), we generally choose probability distributions such as the Exponential Distribution and the Gamma Distribution.
- **For such problems, why do we tend to use these distributions instead of the Normal Distribution? Is there a particular reason?**

Thank you!

Comment: Exponential distributions result from Poisson processes where similar random events in a sense occur independently over time.  Gamma distributions are simple sums of exponential distributions.   Both have nice shapes for positive random variables.

Answer (score 1):

A reason for liking the exponential distribution is its “memoryless” property, which you can easily find pages on by googling that term and the name of the distribution.

And if you are going to study a random variable that takes only positive values, why would you want to use the normal distribution when it has negative values with probability $1/2$?

A rationale for preferring  certain probability distributions is that they have “maximum entropy” subject to some constraint, like having a specified mean value. For example, the unique continuous probability distribution on the positive reals with a specified mean is the exponential distribution with that mean. The unique continuous probability distribution on the real line having a specified mean and variance is the normal distribution with that mean and variance. See the Wikipedia page on maximum entropy distributions.

Comment: @ KCd : Thank you so much for your answer! I liked this interpretation involving Maximum Entropy! If you have time, can you please take a look at this question? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4458150/properties-of-continuous-time-markov-chains Thank you!

Comment: That other question is not anything I can tell you about.